# Telerik Rad Combo and async postbacks in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ajax, telerik, viewstate

it looks like nobody has posted on this.

I have a very typical set up, an ajax update panel is updated when a drop list of offices changes. Each form could have it's own values, for instance each store will have it's own list of employees. Here is where the fun begins. The form can be changed by the drop down (new office) or validated and submitted.

On drop down change, I create a new instance of the same rad combo, bind it to the current data, confirm that the correct data is bound. Then on the return trip I see selected the default user from the previous user. This is a composite control, and firebug shows me that the value for the "text box" that simulates the combo still has the old value. I'm suspecting onViewStateLoaded, but turning viewstate off for the Telerik didn't help any. II don;t need it anyway, cuz I have to put the selected value in another hidden to make a cross page post on submit. Any ideas before I hack this up really bad? Any will be appreciated.

Comment: Get out while you can... that freaking telerik ajax thing has been the bane of my existence for the last few months. It's (IMO) completely broken in modern browsers, esp. webkit, and I've got to do something with a fairly large (in terms of codebase, not so large in terms of users) site that uses the damn thing all over the place. I'm rewriting the entire front end in a framework that doesn't suck.

Comment: I only selected them because they had autocomplete which is one of my requirements. Surprisingly it was one of the few that maintained a selected value. I could not beleieve the AjaxToolKitDropDown didn't support it. And now after 3 months of development and the dept buying the license, I am stuck with these darn things. At least I didb't replace every conbo, just the ones needing autocomplete or some other interaction that off the shelf controls couldn't supply. Now I wish I kept the toolkit and just passed that associative array of selvalue.

Comment: The RadCombobox is a powerful tool and it should only be used when you need features beyond what a basic ASP.NET DropDownList provides. If you don't need the rich features, you can always style a DropDownList to match other Telerik tools using the RadFormDecorator. Used correctly, the Telerik tools fully support all major browsers and we're always here to help if you have trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I would answer your question directly, but I don't have enough info, as I was not able to duplicate the issue here locally.

Have you tried contacting Telerik support, or using their forums?  I've found them to be quite responsive, even offer custom dll's for some solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Like Jeff, I have a difficult time rebuilding your scenario from the description. The fastest way to solve this problem is to open a Telerik Support Ticket. If you can provide a basic sample the exhibits the problem, the support team will quickly respond with a solution. Don't miss that valuable part of your Telerik purchase! That's what separates commercial tools from unsupported options.

If you'd prefer to keep troubleshooting, I'd try stepping back and simplifying your scenario. It sounds like some hacking has already begun and I think that may be leading to unusual results.

Specifically, the step where you create a new RadComboBox on post should not be required. If you can share some more code examples, I'll be happy to help further.